# How to synchronize multiple controls?

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I am looking for pattern in swift to synchronize the state of multiple controls. Say I have `NSSegmentedControl` in the view, `NSMenuItem`s with checkmarks and `NSSegmentedControl` in touch bar. Each of them is sending change to model. But how to synchronize with other two? I can use delegates but it looks like the complexity will grow with number of synchronizable items. Is there a common pattern to approach this problem? I would think of something like subscription to change, so all 3 controls can subscribe to it and receive notification when a change occurs, then use it's own transformation of data to pass to the control. Wonder if there is some mechanism for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism for that, it's the notification model. I imagine you want the view controller to listen for changes and update its controls--not have each control listen for changes and update itself (which is also possible). The basic approach would be to add a notification observer to the view controller (or whatever object you want to be the observer)...

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(nHandler(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "someControlDidChange"), object: segmentedControl)
```

...and a handler to take action on that notification...

```
@objc func nHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let control = notification.object as? UISegmentedControl else {
        return
    }
    // determine which control posted the notification
    // read the control's new value
    // update the other controls
}
```

Then as a control updates its values, it posts notifications...

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "someControlDidChange"), object: self)
```

The `object` here can be `self` if this notification is posted from within the control (i.e. it's subclassed) or the instance of the control itself (i.e. `someSegmentedControl`).

The notification observer and the notification poster allow you to include an optional `object`, as you see in my examples. You should be passing some data within these notifications to allow the observer to determine what object is posting the notification and what value that object has been updated to. Then in the handler of the notification observer, you unwrap that object to get that data.

I have yet to benchmark the costs of posting notifications; I really have no idea how expensive it is. If the delegate approach is too messy and you've written off property observers, the notification model is likely the way to go.

Comment: well, then I need to add observer for all 3 segmented controls. This of course possible, but also making things messy and complicated if having lots of controls, menu and touch bar items. I thought something like binding would help, but as I read binding is mostly used from interface builder(my controls are created programmatically).

Comment: Do the view controllers that contain these controls share a parent view controller?

Comment: All controls that needs to be syncrhonized are in the same view controller